# How to remove the Navigation Bar (prim. and sec.) from the Homepage for the Genesis Framework?

Tags: genesis-theme-framework, menus

How to remove the Navigation Bar (prim. and sec.) from the Homepage for the Genesis Framework?

Answer (score 1):

you have several options..

**A: Create a new page template for your home page**
Create a home.php file in your child theme directory, of course without the navigation(wish is included in (wp_head)

**B: Unregister the Primary and Secundary Nav**

Open your Child theme functions.php file and add this code at the end of the file, just before the closing ?> if there is any. (DO NOT LEAVE ANY BLANK LINE/SPACE after the closing ?> or your code.)

```
// Unregister Menu
add_action('genesis_after_header', 'remove_nav_bar');
function remove_nav_bars() {
    if (is_home()){
        remove_action('genesis_after_header', 'genesis_do_nav');

    }
}
```

**C: Hiding the menu by CSS**

in your style.css

```
/* Hide Navigation Menu in home page*/
.home #nav, .home #subnav {
    display:none;
}
```

You can use any of this options, of course, option **C** is the easiest way.

Answer (score 1):

Just go to Genesis -> Theme Settings -> Navigation Settings, uncheck **Include Primary Navigation Menu?**

No need to coding anything.